# How to set up access to Symfony2 application via web browser?

Tags: php, symfony, vagrant, virtualhost

I have a Linux virtual box, built using Vagrant. I am working on an application built using Symfony2 and wish to use PHP's built in server to host the application. I have got the PHP server running successfully using the command: `php bin/console server:start`. This tells me:

```
 [OK] Web server listening on http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

I've specified the following in the Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.56.109
```

I want to access the application via the browser on my host machine which is running on Windows 7.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: do you have ping your vagrant ip on your host OS ?

Comment: what do you get on `http://192.168.56.109:8000` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default IP for the built-in web server is `127.0.0.1`. In order for it to be visible outside your vagrant machine, you need to bind it to `0.0.0.0`:

```
php bin/console server:start 0.0.0.0
```

Then you access `http://192.168.56.109:8000` and it should work correctly.